# Windows Desktop App Converter asks "How do you want to open this file" (.sp1)

Tags: windows, powershell, converters, uwp, desktop

I'm trying to convert an .net app I finished recently to the UWP so I can upload it to the Windows Store. I tried to follow the guidelines Microsoft has in a couple of videos, but I'm doing something wrong. Here's the instructions I have in PowerShell:

```
.\DesktopAppConverter.sp1 -Installer AAA.Exe -InstallerArguments "/S /L=1033" 
    -Destination ".\AAAOut" -PackageName "AAA" -Publisher "CN=AAA" 
    -Version 0.0.0.1 -ExpandBaseImage D:\Install\Image\CN=BaseImage-14361.wim -Verbosed
```

Probably the use of the image is not correct and maybe there are other problems. I don't have experience using containers unfortunately(CN).

Thank you very much! All help will be greatly appreciated :)
Bobby

Answer (score 1):

Your first line needs to read .ps1 (it is a PowerShell script), not sp1. Your code should look like this:

.\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -Installer AAA.Exe -InstallerArguments "/S /L=1033" 
    -Destination ".\AAAOut" -PackageName "AAA" -Publisher "CN=AAA" 
    -Version 0.0.0.1 -ExpandBaseImage D:\Install\Image\CN=BaseImage-14361.wim -Verbose

Also, if you haven't already expanded that base image the above will fail. You'll need to expand the image file ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your converting (is your Windows 10 version equial to *.wim image file?), but I can recommend you to convert using Visual Studio 15. That looks much more easy. You can read about how to do it here:

[Announcing the new Desktop to UWP Packaging Project for Visual Studio 15](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/05/17/new-desktop-to-uwp-packaging-project-for-visual-studio-15/)